# Cause of weird wheel failure on homemade utility trailer

Tags: wheels, axle, trailer, rear-differential

I have a homemade utility trailer that's made from an old car or truck axle. I inherited it from my late father-in-law who bought it off a guy in his neighborhood and I've been using for over 15 years. I've pulled this trailer for thousands of miles hauling furniture, motorcycles, mulch, trash, etc.

Recently it started making a clunking noise. I thought it was coming from the hitch but I've found that one of the wheels has failed in a very interesting way[image: failed wheel].

Has anyone ever see a wheel fail like this?  I haven't ever removed a wheel from it but I wonder if the lugnuts were loose and fretted the wheel, but didn't come off due to nature's loctite (rust). Here's a couple other pictures of the rear axle it's made from. Does anyone know what (almost cartainly American) car or truck it's made from?

[image: axle left]

[image: axle right]

Comment: If you have a picture of the front end of the differential, I'm thinking it might be a bit easier to recognize. Also, if you could put a tap measure up against the "good" side wheel to give scale to the distance between bolts (across two bolts not next to each other), that would also give us the axle lug pattern (ie: 5 x ??).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen that before but NEVER to that extreme!  I am amazed that the wheel did not fall off as it doesn't appear that anything, other than just the edges of the nuts, is holding this wheel on.

My guess is that the nuts loosened over time but the trailer kept being used and the wear just happened, mile after miles, until we're here.

You might look at the axle and see if it has a manufacturer or part number on it.

Comment: Or were not tightened.